# SQL SELECT query conditional for multiple possible values

Tags: sql, select

I have the following data:

| id | customer_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Shipped |
| 2 | 1 | In Progress |
| 3 | 1 | Cancelled |
| 4 | 2 | Shipped |
| 5 | 2 | In Progress |
| 6 | 3 | Shipped |

How do I do a SQL query to SELECT a row for each customer based on the status?

If the customer has a status of 'In Progress', then return only that in the results.
If the customer does not have a status of 'In Progress', but does have a status of 'Shipped', then return that instead.

So the results would be:

| id | customer_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | In Progress |
| 5 | 2 | In Progress |
| 6 | 3 | Shipped |

Comment: Have a separate table where you store the different status values, and their priority. JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

One option of tackling this problem is:

- filtering out any status different than either 'Shipped' or 'In Progress', with a `WHERE` clause
- using `FIRST_VALUE`, partitioned by "*customer_id*", ordered by "*id*" to get your last "*id*" and "*status*"
- aggregating on duplicate records, using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           FIRST_VALUE(id)      OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS id,
           customer_id,
           FIRST_VALUE(status_) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS status_
FROM tab
WHERE status_ IN ('Shipped', 'In Progress')
```

This is likely to work on almost all the most common DBMS'.

Answer (score 0):

A bit complex, as I need two common table expressions:

```
-- your input, don't use in final query
WITH                                  
indata(id,customer_id,status) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'Shipped'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'In Progress'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,'Cancelled'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,'Shipped'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,'In Progress'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,3,'Shipped'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
w_rank AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id
  , status
  , CASE status
      WHEN 'Shipped'     THEN 1
      WHEN 'In Progress' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Cancelled'   THEN 0
      ELSE                   -1
    END AS rnk
  FROM indata
)
,
grp AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id
  , MAX(rnk) AS rnk
  FROM w_rank
  GROUP BY
    customer_id
)
SELECT
  indata.id
, indata.customer_id
, indata.status
FROM grp
JOIN w_rank USING(customer_id,rnk)
JOIN indata USING(customer_id,status)
ORDER BY 1;
-- out  id | customer_id |   status   
-- out ----+-------------+------------
-- out   2 |           1 | In Progress
-- out   5 |           2 | In Progress
-- out   6 |           3 | Shipped
```

Can be your DBMS does not support the USING() clause in joins - then use the ON clause.